# Django Template Error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I fetched tweets from twitter. In the template tweets loop, I tried to print how long ago this tweet was created. So this is what I tried:

```
<li class="twitter-feed-block-content">
  {{ tweet.text }}
  <span class="when">
    {{ tweet.created_at|timesince }}
  </span>
</li>
```

`{{tweet.text}}` is printing correctly. However, when I add the next line `{{ tweet.created_at|timesince }}` I get the following error:

```
Exception Value:     'unicode' object has no attribute 'year' Exception
Location:   REMOVED_BY_ME/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/timesince.py
in timesince, line 29 Python
Executable: REMOVED_BY_ME/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
```

The `tweet.created_at` is a string. Is this the reason? if so, how I can convert it so that it works seamless with `timesince` filter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how I've solved the question. As I told, I wanted to create custom filter as a last resort only.

So, i've created a filter named `strtotimesince`. i'm putting it here so that it helps if someone faces similar problem.

```
from django.utils import timesince

@register.filter(name='strtotimesince')
def strtotimesince(value,format=None):
    if not value:
        return u''

    if not format:
        format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"
    try:
        convert_to_datetime = datetime.strptime(value, format)
        if convert_to_datetime:
            return "%s ago" % timesince.timesince(convert_to_datetime)
    except:
        return ''
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this snippet. Just to let you know, I've used this in my own projects together with [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/). No need for that pesky format guessing anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Convert it into a DateTime object using python strptime

```
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime("2012-10-11", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: I don't think I can do it in template! can I?

Comment: i know that i can do it in views. but I wanted to get it done in template. I do not want iterate over the tweets in the view. please tell me alternatives other than 'view' and 'custom filter'. those two are the last things I wanna do.

Comment: I'm guessing you could define a `to_datetime` method for `tweet` and use that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use custom filter?

Comment: You could just define a custom filter and use it in the template.